# Cannot run exe in powershell

Tags: c, powershell, console-application, mingw-w64

I have a simple hello world program compiled by Mingw-w64. It works ok in cmd, but in powershell it just freeze and I get no output after running it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

[image: CMD screenshot]

[image: powershell screenshot]

I tried to copy the exe file to another computer. The powershell in the second computer can run the file, so it seems to be a local powershell setting problem. Anyone know what could cause the problem?

Follow up: I installed newer powershell 7 then it works. Still don't understand why the native powershell (version 5.1.19041.1320) doesn't work.

Comment: Can't reproduce (Win 10 powershell)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the slash incorrectly.

You wrote:

```
.\hi.exe
```

but you should have written:

```
./hi.exe
```